# WPF datagrid - flexible binding for group headers

Tags: wpf, datagrid, collectionviewsource

I have a wpf datagrid with grouped rows, implemented using a `CollectionViewSource`.  It appears the group header templates bind directly to `CollectionViewGroup` objects, but for some reason these aren't very accessible inside the CVS.  You give the `CollectionViewSource` the group names, and it handles generating the CVG's behind the scenes.  This makes things difficult if you want the group header styles to bind to something other than what few properties the CVG's expose, like `Name` and `ItemCount`.

Basically, I want every group to have a `Status` property, probably to be visually indicated by the group header background color.  This `Status` can change, so somehow the header will have to detect `propertychanged` notifications.  But since `CollectionViewGroup` does not have a `Status` property, and I cannot supply my own CVGs to the `CollectionViewSource`, I've no idea how to do this simple task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out eventually.  The `Name` property of `CollectionViewGroup` is an object, so you can create a group view model of desired properties, then give that as the `Name` when adding group descriptions to the `CollectionViewSource`.  And then in the xaml just do nested binding to `Name.whatever` for the group header controls.

I set it up like so (vb.net to follow):

```
  Me.BindedCV = New Data.CollectionViewSource
  Me.BindedCV.GroupDescriptions.Add(New Data.PropertyGroupDescription("ProductGroup"))
```

This means all rows (more specifically, the viewmodels that the rows are binded to) will be grouped according to a property called `ProductGroup`.  Now I add my own group objects to the `CollectionView` group descriptions:

```
        Dim pg = New ProductGroupVM(pd.Index)
        Me._ProductGroupVMs.Add(pg)
        Me.BindedCV.GroupDescriptions(0).GroupNames.Add(pg)
```

So by adding `pg` to the `GroupNames` collection means it can now be referenced and binded to in the xaml group header styling - it is the `Name` object.  Note that I also added `pg` to a second private collection I created called `_ProductGroupVMs`.  This is a bit hackish, but that way I can keep a reference to all my group objects - when I create the row viewmodels, they will have a `ProductGroup` property, and `ProductGroup` needs to point to the right `pg` in order for them to be grouped correctly.  There might be cleaner ways to do it but that's the route I went.

Comment: Tekito, it would be exception to have have a small example from you as I was attempting to sort this out yesterday. I guess my main question is, how do you tell the CollectionViewSource which property of the 'Name' object to use to group by?

Comment: @dansan Ok I added some code.  But my `CVS` does not group by a property of `Name` - it groups by reference to the `Name` objects themselves.  The binded objects of the rows all have a property called `ProductGroup` that points to the `Name` object they belong to.